# Installing bare minimum mongo package on ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

We are working on a a system that uses cloud runner, where we have a tech like Spring + Gradle plus Mongo.

The system is containerized and runs on cloud-run in gcp. However, gcp has a hard limit of 2gb on container size, which we are trying to fit into, as of now.

Thus, every mb of storage and RAM becomes crutial for us.

I realized that lot ot the mongo utilieis, like export, restore. may be journaling etc is not used by our tool, and thus it can be skipped from installation, and we can save up some space.

While I can manually go and delete the unnwanted files, it can potentially open up few other problems. so what I want to know is

**Is there any option while installing mondogb, that will install only bare minimum needed for a mongo server?**

We would like so explore it, as it can save few mb's for us, which is critical at the moment.

Comment: All mongo utilities together may have a size of 150MB - do you really think these few MB's will save your life? I don't know which version you will need, but for most of them you can select the "server" package which is quite small.

Comment: There are two parts of it. 1.Mongo installation, 2- the disk and RAM space that mongo blocks when it starts.. as I see, its blocking upto 300mb space, while we will be having hardly 1000 records in the database in total..

Comment: Why are you concerned about disc space if you have only 1000 documents? 2GB is plenty of space for that.

Comment: The problem is, whether we use or not, mongo is allocation about 300mb space for data directory, and creating placeholder files.. I am trying to fix that, along with other exe stuff.

Comment: @Downvoter, I would request you to provide your opinion how this question can be improved.. Its a genuine case I am facing in my product, and needed advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the smallest possible installation you can place just the files you want on your target system. MongoDB will run with just the `mongod` binary for example.

Package managers and "normal" installation solutions install complete packages for ease of use and are set up for automatic updates, etc.